# iOS: setContentSize is causing my entire UIScrollView frame to jump

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

There is probably a simple solution to this problem that I'm missing, but I can't seem to find the cause.

**Problem:** Every time I call setContentSize on my scroll view, it causes the entire scrollview frame to shift.

**Question:** Why does its position reset every time setContentSize is called? and how do I get it to stop?

*Notes:*

- The contentOffSet within the Scrollview is fine. It's the entire
  scrollview frame that jumps to its original position.
- The scroll view is meant to move up and down with a button press, revealing the UIView underneath.
  -- This works fine, but when a cell is opened, and CollapseClick calls setContentSize on itself (the scrollview), the entire scrollview jumps back up prematurely
- Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

### Layout:

- Simple Layout: 1 scrollview(full screen), 1 container for UIView(height: 120 point) that appears and disappears as the Scrollview moves up and down.

[image]

MasterView.m (portion)

```
-(void)showPostShout{
    CGRect newCCFrame = myCollapseClick.frame;//<----myCollapseClick is the UIScrollView

    if (!postShoutOpen) {
        newCCFrame.origin.y += 120;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.4 delay:0  options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            self.postShoutContainer.alpha = 1;
            myCollapseClick.frame= newCCFrame;

        } completion: ^(BOOL finished){
            NSLog(@"finished!");
        }];
    } else{
        newCCFrame.origin.y -= 120;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            self.postShoutContainer.alpha = 0;
            myCollapseClick.frame= newCCFrame;
        } completion: ^(BOOL finished){
            NSLog(@"finished2!");
        }];
    }

    postShoutOpen = !postShoutOpen;
}
```

CollapseableClick.m (offending portion?)

```
-(void)repositionCollapseClickCellsBelowIndex:(int)index withOffset:(float)offset {
    for (int yy = index+1; yy < self.dataArray.count; yy++) {
        CollapseClickCell *cell = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:yy];
        cell.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y + offset, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height);
    }

    // Resize self.ContentSize
    CollapseClickCell *lastCell = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:self.dataArray.count - 1];
    [self setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, lastCell.frame.origin.y + lastCell.frame.size.height + kCCPad)];

}
```

collapseableclick.m (whole)

```
//
//  CollapseClick.m
//  CollapseClick
//
//  Created by Ben Gordon on 2/28/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Ben Gordon. All rights reserved.
//

#import "CollapseClick.h"
//#import "UIScrollView+SVPullToRefresh.h"

@implementation CollapseClick
@synthesize CollapseClickDelegate;


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.isClickedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[CollapseClickDelegate numberOfCellsForCollapseClick]];
        self.dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[CollapseClickDelegate numberOfCellsForCollapseClick]];
        [self reloadCollapseClick];
    }
    return self;
}


#pragma mark - Load Data
-(void)reloadCollapseClick {
    // Set Up: Height
    float totalHeight = 0;

    // If Arrays aren't Init'd, Init them
    if (!(self.isClickedArray)) {
        self.isClickedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[CollapseClickDelegate numberOfCellsForCollapseClick]];
    }

    if (!(self.dataArray)) {
        self.dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[CollapseClickDelegate numberOfCellsForCollapseClick]];
    }

    // Make sure they are clear
    [self.isClickedArray removeAllObjects];
    [self.dataArray removeAllObjects];

    // Remove all subviews
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }

    // Add cells
    for (int xx = 0; xx < [CollapseClickDelegate numberOfCellsForCollapseClick]; xx++) {
        // Create Cell
        ///add delegate methods for agree/disagree debaters here 
        CollapseClickCell *cell = [CollapseClickCell newCollapseClickCellWithTitle:[CollapseClickDelegate titleForCollapseClickAtIndex:xx] stats:[CollapseClickDelegate statsForCollapseClick:xx] index:xx content:[CollapseClickDelegate viewForCollapseClickContentViewAtIndex:xx]];


        // Set cell.TitleView's backgroundColor
        if ([(id)CollapseClickDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(colorForCollapseClickTitleViewAtIndex:)]) {
            cell.TitleView.backgroundColor = [CollapseClickDelegate colorForCollapseClickTitleViewAtIndex:xx];
        }
        else {
            cell.TitleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.4 alpha:1.0];
        }


        // Set cell.TitleLabel's Color
        if ([(id)CollapseClickDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(colorForTitleLabelAtIndex:)]) {
            cell.TitleLabel.textColor = [CollapseClickDelegate colorForTitleLabelAtIndex:xx];
        }
        else {
            cell.TitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        }


        // Set cell.TitleArrow's Color
        if ([(id)CollapseClickDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(colorForTitleArrowAtIndex:)]) {
            [cell.TitleArrow drawWithColor:[CollapseClickDelegate colorForTitleArrowAtIndex:xx]];
        }
        else {
            [cell.TitleArrow drawWithColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.35]];
        }

        // Set cell.ContentView's size
        cell.ContentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, kCCHeaderHeight + kCCPad, self.frame.size.width, cell.ContentView.frame.size.height);

        // Set cell's size
        cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, totalHeight, self.frame.size.width, kCCHeaderHeight);


        // Add target to Button
        [cell.TitleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didSelectCollapseClickButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        // Add cell
        [self addSubview:cell];

        // Add to DataArray & isClickedArray
        [self.isClickedArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
        [self.dataArray addObject:cell];

        // Calculate totalHeight
        totalHeight += kCCHeaderHeight + kCCPad;
    }


    // Set self's ContentSize and ContentOffset
    [self setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, totalHeight)];
    [self setContentOffset:CGPointZero];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]  postNotificationName:@"CollapseClickUpdated" object: self ];
}



#pragma mark - Reposition Cells
-(void)repositionCollapseClickCellsBelowIndex:(int)index withOffset:(float)offset {
    for (int yy = index+1; yy < self.dataArray.count; yy++) {
        CollapseClickCell *cell = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:yy];
        cell.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y + offset, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height);
    }

    // Resize self.ContentSize
    CollapseClickCell *lastCell = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:self.dataArray.count - 1];
    [self setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, lastCell.frame.origin.y + lastCell.frame.size.height + kCCPad)];

}


#pragma mark - Did Click
-(void)didSelectCollapseClickButton:(UIButton *)titleButton {
    BOOL isOpen = NO;

    // Cell is OPEN -> CLOSED
    if ([[self.isClickedArray objectAtIndex:titleButton.tag] boolValue] == YES) {
        [self closeCollapseClickCellAtIndex:titleButton.tag animated:YES];
    }
    // Cell is CLOSED -> OPEN
    else {
        [self openCollapseClickCellAtIndex:titleButton.tag animated:YES];
        isOpen = YES;
    }

    // Call delegate method
    if ([(id)CollapseClickDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didClickCollapseClickCellAtIndex:isNowOpen:)]) {
        [CollapseClickDelegate didClickCollapseClickCellAtIndex:titleButton.tag isNowOpen:isOpen];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Open CollapseClickCell
-(void)openCollapseClickCellAtIndex:(int)index animated:(BOOL)animated {
    // Check if it's not open first
    if ([[self.isClickedArray objectAtIndex:index] boolValue] != YES) {
        float duration = 0;
        if (animated) {
            duration = 0.25;
        }
        [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
            // Resize Cell
            CollapseClickCell *cell = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:index];
            cell.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, cell.frame.size.width, cell.ContentView.frame.origin.y + cell.ContentView.frame.size.height + kCCPad);

            // Change Arrow orientation
            CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
            cell.TitleArrow.transform = transform;

            // Change isClickedArray
            [self.isClickedArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];

            // Reposition all CollapseClickCells below Cell
            [self repositionCollapseClickCellsBelowIndex:index withOffset:cell.ContentView.frame.size.height + kCCPad];
        }];
    }
}

-(void)openCollapseClickCellsWithIndexes:(NSArray *)indexArray animated:(BOOL)animated {
    // This works off of NSNumbers for each Index
    for (int ii = 0; ii < indexArray.count; ii++) {
        id indexID = indexArray[ii];
        if ([indexID isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
            [self openCollapseClickCellAtIndex:[indexID intValue] animated:animated];
        }
    }

}



#pragma mark - Close CollapseClickCell
-(void)closeCollapseClickCellAtIndex:(int)index animated:(BOOL)animated {
    // Check if it's open first
    if ([[self.isClickedArray objectAtIndex:index] boolValue] == YES) {
        float duration = 0;
        if (animated) {
            duration = 0.25;
        }
        [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
            // Resize Cell
            CollapseClickCell *cell = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:index];
            cell.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, cell.frame.size.width, kCCHeaderHeight);

            // Change Arrow orientation
            CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
            cell.TitleArrow.transform = transform;

            // Change isClickedArray
            [self.isClickedArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];

            // Reposition all CollapseClickCells below Cell
            [self repositionCollapseClickCellsBelowIndex:index withOffset:-1*(cell.ContentView.frame.size.height + kCCPad)];
        }];
    }
}

-(void)closeCollapseClickCellsWithIndexes:(NSArray *)indexArray animated:(BOOL)animated {
    // This works off of NSNumbers for each Index
    for (int ii = 0; ii < indexArray.count; ii++) {
        id indexID = indexArray[ii];
        if ([indexID isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
            [self closeCollapseClickCellAtIndex:[indexID intValue] animated:animated];
        }
    }
}


#pragma mark - CollapseClickCell for Index
-(CollapseClickCell *)collapseClickCellForIndex:(int)index {
    if ([[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:index] isKindOfClass:[CollapseClickCell class]]) {
        return [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:index];
    }

    return nil;
}


#pragma mark - Scroll To Cell
-(void)scrollToCollapseClickCellAtIndex:(int)index animated:(BOOL)animated {
    CollapseClickCell *cell = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:index];
    [self setContentOffset:CGPointMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y) animated:animated];
}


#pragma mark - Content View for Cell
-(UIView *)contentViewForCellAtIndex:(int)index {
    CollapseClickCell *cell = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:index];
    return cell.ContentView;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a simple solution: Turn off Auto-layout.

For me, I didn't turn it off for my whole storyboard, just a nib I had loaded in. (intended to be used as a widget throughout the site.) Problem solved.

The WWDC 2012 video “Session 228 - Best Practices for Mastering Auto Layout” explains and addresses the problem, starting at 30m45s.